# How can I create variable variables in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm doing this

```
mcomp7d101.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("javascript:Compartir("+id7d101+");");
}

mcomp7d102.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("javascript:Compartir("+id7d101+");");
}

mcomp7d103.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("javascript:Compartir("+id7d101+");");
}

mcomp7d150.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("javascript:Compartir("+id7d101+");");
}
```

you get the idea :)

How can I use a for loop to do something like:

```
for(ii = 101; ii < 150; ii++)
{
    mcomp7d+ii.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("javascript:Compartir("+id7d+ii);");
    }
}
```

I'm getting a syntax error. It seems that I can't create variable variables in compiled languages.

Comment: i hate sintax-- so regressive.

Comment: Unexpected economics joke on stack! Got me thinking anyway - are you suggesting the poor have a monopoly on sin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
for(ii = 101; ii < 150; ii++) 
{ 
    this["mcomp7d" + ii].onRelease = function() 
    { 
        getURL("javascript:Compartir(" + this['id7d' + ii] + ");"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Guess, you not totally correct:
getURL("javascript:Compartir('id7d" + ii + "');");
this will pass string to "Compartir", but he needs to pass value of id7d101 variable to all functions. Leave like this:
getURL("javascript:Compartir(" + id7d101 + ");");

Comment: Thanks for the correction radistao. I think it would probably be this then getURL("javascript:Compartir(" + this['id7d' + ii] + ");");